# Consulta por múltiples campos

Tags: sql

Existe alguna forma mediante un **UN SOLO** select de recuperar por ejemplo los valores de Juan Perez (registro 1) y de Carlos Gonzalez (registro 6)
La tabla tiene muchos registros y al resultado de un select, le debo realizar un update.  Para no realizar el update uno a uno es que realizo la consulta.  Muchas Gracias.  Sdos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como planteas tu pregunta entiendo que deseas obtener mediante una consulta los registros de Juan Pérez y Carlos González para posteriormente hacer una actualización de sus datos uno por uno pero del lado de tu programa. Para obtener ambos registros realiza la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Numero
FROM usuarios
WHERE 
(Nombre = 'Juan' AND Apellido = 'Pérez')
OR (Nombre = 'Carlos' AND Apellido = 'González');
```

Sin embargo, la búsqueda de ambos usuarios sería mejor realizarla por su clave primaria de la siguiente forma puesto que, pueden existir varios usuarios con la misma combinación de nombre y apellido y en un futuro, la consulta no solo podría devolver 2 usuarios sino "x" cantidad.

```
SELECT Nombre, Apellido, Numero
FROM usuarios
WHERE 
Id = 1 OR Id = 6;
```

Comment: Gracias a ambos

Comment: Buen día y gracias por la respuesta, la actualización si o si se tiene que hacer uno por uno, no se puede actualizar en un solo update para los dos registros? Gracias

Comment: @Damian si se pueden actualizar multiples campos y registros en un solo update. El problema es a que valor los queres actualizar

Comment: @Garduño suponte que existe otro campo, con valores posibles 1 o o(cero) y están todos en 1 y quiero hacer el update para esos dos registros a 0(cero).Como lo haría, gracias sdios

Comment: @Damian intenta de la siguiente forma: UPDATE tabla SET estatus = 0 WHERE Id IN (1, 6); No obstante, en tu programa para hacerlo de forma dinámica primero deberas agrupas todos los ID´s a actualizar dentro de un arreglo y al momento de ejecutar el UPDATE tendrías que remplazar IN (1, 6) por IN (arreglo).

Comment: Hola, no tengo un id sino un PK compuesta por varios campos, por lo cual no podria hacer el update como dice, habria otra forma? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Claro que existe, para obtener ambos registros, puedes utilizar el operador `or`. Dado que cada registro se compone de nombre y apellido, en realidad va a ser una combinación de `and` y `or`, algo como:

```
select *
  from MiTabla
 where (Nombre = 'Juan' and Apellido = 'Perez')
    or (Nombre = 'Carlos' and Apellido = 'Gonzalez');
```

Presta atención a que he utilizado paréntesis `()` para que el motor no tenga problemas al localizar los registros. De otra forma, dada la precedencia de los operadores, podría no obtener los resultados esperados. Hago esto siempre que mezclo `and` y `or` (u otros operadores lógicos).

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, en el caso de que los pares de datos (nombre y apellido) sean numerosos y lo he obtenido mediante un select, como podria, a ese conjunto de datos, hacerle un update, muchas gracias. Sdos

Comment: Si ya tienes los datos dentro de tu programa, suponiendo que hay una llave primaria, puedes construir un `update` afectando solo los registros de tu interés, utilizando la llave primaria. Por ejemplo, si la llave es simple, puedes construir un `update MiTabla set MiCampo = 'MiValor' where idMiTabla in (1, 2, 10, 15)`